# Data handling in c++

Tags: c++, csv

I'm working on a program and my "database" is some .csv files.

I have a list of objects in a .csv with some information about each. Which is the best-appropriate way to treat the "data".

- Work with fstream, meaning that everytime that I want to modify the data, or I want to read something I will directly work with my files with the tools of fstream
- Or, at the beginning of the program I will load the data in a vector, read,write on the vector and in the end of the program I delete the previous file and load the new one.

In a matter of performance will it be different? Considering that the objects are numerous.

Comment: What happens when you follow your second approach and the file is modified during execution of your program? Besides obvious differences between those two approaches, not enough context imo, even in a matter of performance impact.

Comment: Open, read into cache, and close the file. Periodically write the cache to file if it has been modified. Definitely write on exit. You don't even have to delete the old file. Just open the file and write over it.

Comment: my point was made clear I think. By fstream I mean the input/output stream class

Comment: so you are suggesting to load the file in a vector/array and proceed that way ? I know @mpiatek that would be a big problem, but if data is passed in a vector and I save the data every x amount of time, it would be a lot easier

Comment: Counter to @mpiatek 's point: What if the user has opened and locked the file when the program needs to read it? Better to read the file under controlled circumstances. Fewer surprises. If users modifying the file during runtime is a concern and you have to heed those modifications, monitor the state of the file. If the file is modified, open and refresh the cache when it is safe to do so.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ is a good place to start

Comment: @Brandon I know how to work with files. This is a completely different question that I have.

Comment: Okay but still lack of context. How often do you read\write? What amount of data we are talking about? When you want to do some operation on data do you need the data to be always up-to-date? Do you write only after you read? Can the file be accessed by for example multiple instances of your program? @Theo.Fanis I'm not saying the second one is bad, I'm just saying there is not enough information to answer this question. E.g. file might be small with not too many read/writes, nothing else is writing to it etc.

Comment: @mpiatek I tried not to be super specific about an instance of my program, as I wanted to know, when to use the first one and when the second one. I understand that they are both good approaches but in different type of programs.

Comment: Most important question: Is your data fixed-size? In other words, are all comma-separated values the same length in every row? If that is the case, performing the edits in-place has significant advantages with respect to performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is more of a combination rather than choosing A or B. Especially choosing only A. is not safe as multiple components could access the file simultaneously. Plus if there are many updates then using streams each time could be make your code very slow.

Therefore I believe that you should use B but also take care of the implementation to persist your data in a safe way (write your data in the file).

Regarding the data structure, this depends on the usage. One important question to ask here is whether there are many insertions and deletions. If this is the case then it would be more efficient to use a [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead of a vector, as the list provides instant time insertions and [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is not appropriate for this purpose.

If the data include a unique attribute and fast lookups are needed then a hash or a map would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Take the CSV parser from my CSVtoC utility.

http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/

CSV files are not good for dynamic update as the records are not fixed in known disk physical locations. (The alternative is to contrive the CSV so that that doesn't hold, but it's a delicate and messy approach).

Reading a CSV is hard, writing one is trivial.